# 構造体のプロパティについて

Tags: swift

コード:

```
struct hoge {
    var a: Int = 0
}

var obj: hoge = hoge(a: 10)
println(obj.a) //一度目のprintln
obj.a = 5
println(obj.a) //二度目のprintln
```

出力結果:

```
10
5
```

コード:

```
struct hoge {
    var a: Int = 0
}

var obj: hoge = hoge(a: 10)
//println(obj.a)　//一度目のprintlnをコメントアウト
obj.a = 5
println(obj.a) //二度目のprintln
```

出力結果:

```
10
```

上記の様に、一度目のprintlnを実行するかしないかで、二度目のprintlnの結果が変わってきます。（「obj.a = 5」が処理されていない？）

実行環境は、http://www.runswiftlang.com/ です。

これはswiftの仕様なのでしょうか？
だとしたらどう理解すれば良いでしょうか？

それとも、http://www.runswiftlang.com/ のバグなのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> それとも、http://www.runswiftlang.com/ のバグなのでしょうか？

その線がいちばん濃いと思います。

Xcode 6.3.2のPlaygroundで実行した結果がこちら。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Xcode 6.3.2のCommandLineToolで実行した結果がこちら。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: やっぱりバグなんしょうね。
スッキリしました。
ありがとうございました。